# Как реализовать на нативном JavaScript отложенный ховер по элементу, когда курсор уже ушел с элемента

Tags: javascript, hover, settimeout

Добрый день!

Прошу подсказать, в чем дело, почему не срабатывает удаление добавленного на элемент свойства через 3 сек. (не срабатывает функция с `setTimeout`).

Задача: нужно реализовать отложенное состояние наведения на элемент - когда наводим на элемент-карточку товара, например, то ничего не происходит, а когда курсор уходит с карточки, то карточка (c классом-модификатором `.card--selected`) на какое-то время (например, 3 сек.) меняет свой вид. Как новичку в JS, еще не очевидна причина).

```js
var goods = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

goods.forEach(function(notBuy) {
  notBuy.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
    if (evt.target === this) {
      if (this.classList.contains("card--selected")) {
        this.classList.add("card--hover");
        var timerId = setTimeout(function() {
          goods.classList.remove("card--hover");
        }, 3000);
        clearTimeout(timerId);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.card__inner-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.card__inner-wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: -11px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #1698d9;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.card__name {
  display: block;
}

.card__name--hover {
  display: none;
}

.card--hover .card__name {
  display: none;
}

.card--hover .card__name--selected-hover {
  display: block;
  color: #d91667;
}
```

```html
<article class="card card--selected">
  <a class="card__inner-wrapper" href="#">
    <span class="card__name">Лого в обычном состоянии</span>
    <span class="card__name card__name--selected-hover">Лого-по-ховеру на 
    уже выбранном товаре</span>
    <h2 class="card__title">Наименование товара</h2>
  </a>
  <p class="card__call">Текст<a class="card__link" href="#">купи</a></p>
  <p class="card__call card__call--active">Текст2</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в коде несколько ошибок:

1 - вы пытаетесь удалить класс `card--hover` у списка DOM элементов `.goods`, хотя необходимо удалять у наведенного элемента

2 - вы зачем то очищаете установленный Timeout, хотя этого здесь делать не нужно

Предлагаю вам рабочий вариант:

```js
var goods = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

goods.forEach(function(notBuy) {
  notBuy.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(evt) {
    var _this = this //сохраняем ссылку на наведенный объект

    if (evt.target === _this) {
      if (_this.classList.contains("card--selected")) {
        _this.classList.add("card--hover");

        setTimeout(function() {
          _this.classList.remove("card--hover"); //вместо goods используем сохранненную ранее ссылку           
        }, 3000);
        //clearTimeout(timerId); - тут этого не нужно
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.card__inner-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.card__inner-wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: -11px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #1698d9;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.card__name {
  display: block;
}

.card__name--hover {
  display: none;
}

.card--hover .card__name {
  display: none;
}

.card__name--selected-hover {
  display: none;
}

.card--hover .card__name--selected-hover {
  display: block;
  color: #d91667;
}
```

```html
<article class="card card--selected">
  <a class="card__inner-wrapper" href="#">
    <span class="card__name">Лого в обычном состоянии</span>
    <span class="card__name card__name--selected-hover">Лого-по-ховеру на 
    уже выбранном товаре</span>
    <h2 class="card__title">Наименование товара</h2>
  </a>
  <p class="card__call">Текст<a class="card__link" href="#">купи</a></p>
  <p class="card__call card__call--active">Текст2</p>
</article>

<article class="card card--selected">
  <a class="card__inner-wrapper" href="#">
    <span class="card__name">Лого в обычном состоянии</span>
    <span class="card__name card__name--selected-hover">Лого-по-ховеру на 
    уже выбранном товаре</span>
    <h2 class="card__title">Наименование товара</h2>
  </a>
  <p class="card__call">Текст<a class="card__link" href="#">купи</a></p>
  <p class="card__call card__call--active">Текст2</p>
</article>
```

P.S.: Вам вместо `mouseout` необходимо было использовать `mouseleave`, подробнее почитайте [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave).

Comment: Спасибо за код-ревью! Заметила, что данное условие по наведению-уходу срабатывает только в том случае, если уход с карточки осуществляется через ее основание-bottom (то есть движение курсора мышки сверху-вниз (1)) и если навести снова на карточку (курсор снизу-вверх), то по наведению сразу меняется состояние карточки на то, которое должно быть при уходе с карточки после наведения (2). 1 - это из-за особенностей браузера? 2 - наверное нужна заглушка по функции наведения на карточку?

Comment: Дополнение по 2 - хотя когда навожу на карточку (через bottom) на 1й ее элемент, то состояние по по наведению не меняется, а вот если далее перемещаю курс вверх к следующему элементу, то срабатывает сценарий по уходу с карточки. Тогда нужно какое-то ограничение по движению по элементам в рамках карточки

Comment: Немного не понял ваш сценарий перемещения, можете подробнее описать его? =)

Comment: Даниил, сценарий по заданию: если наводим курсор мыши на раннее выбранный товар, то ничего не происходит, но после того как курсор уходит с товара, на некоторое время меняется вид товара. Что вижу сейчас: если навожу на товар движение - снизу-вверх и остаюсь на товаре, то вид товара на некоторое время меняется на тот, который должен быть при уходе с него. Ухожу с товара (срабатывает только при движении с товара сверху-вниз), вид товара опять меняется на некоторое время - как и должно быть по заданию.

Comment: То есть почему-то по наведению эффект срабатывает сразу и еще срабатывает только при определенном условии - при движении с товара вниз или при наведении на товар снизу-вверх. Карточка товара состоит из нескольких элементов - отдельно ссылка-изображение и отдельно абзац с другой ссылкой.

Comment: Елена, приведите еще пожалуйста `HTML` и `CSS` код в вопросе (просто в моем примере эффект применяется при движении в любом направлении). =)

Comment: Данил, добавила код.

Comment: Елена, я обновил ответ, посмотрите (после кода добавил небольшое пояснение).

Comment: Данил, большое спасибо за ответ и ссылку! Теперь все ОК.

Comment: Елена, на здоровье)